# How to create a table in mysql with a random name?

Tags: mysql

I have a procedure that update a table. However, I need to back up the table each time prior updating it.  So the only way I can backup the table via procedure is by create a table and inserting all the information from one table to another.

So What I need to do is create a table name with a random value to distinguish the different tables. The ideal solution will be "New_Table_Name_TIMESTAMP" so append timestamp to a string.

My Question is how to create a table with a timestamp added to it's name
New_table_name_201412301044

I have tried the following

```
DECLARE new_table varchar(100) DEFAULT '';
SET new_table = CONCAT('WORKFLOW_BU_', client_id_to_update, '_', unix_timestamp() );    

CREATE TABLE data_import.new_table LIKE development.inventory_engine;
INSERT INTO data_import.new_table
SELECT * FROM development.inventory_engine;
```

but it create a table name called "new_table" and not the variable

Thanks

Comment: Copying an entire table every time you update just seems like the terribly wrong way to go about it.

Comment: I need it for backup in case something went wrong. + it is a small table.

Comment: Using transactions or mysqldump can handle those cases: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html

Comment: Why don't you copy the rows that you're updating into another table called 'backup' and add a timestamp column instead of copying the whole table?

Comment: I don't know what rows will be updates. + the table it about 10K records so it is very small. I just want to know how to dynamically create a table with unix_timestamp appended to it.

Comment: from you UPDATE statement, if you do a SELECT instead you'll pull back what rows will be updated before the update If it has a WHERE clause then use the same WHERE for your select and it'll pull back all rows that will be updated.

Comment: If you must do it like table_with_timestamp, you can always build a dynamic SQL and prepare it and execute it, but it sounds like a bad solution

Comment: By I need to back up the entire table so I can easily restore it if I have to. 10k records is a very small table.

Comment: I would create an audit table like your_table_name_audit with the colums as columnBlahBefore, columnBlahAfter then I create a before trigger on your table to backup your data! I'm just improving the @TinTran idea

Comment: @JorgeCampos, a trigger sounds like a good idea

Comment: @Mike, you state in your question "the only way I can backup the table via procedure is by create a table and inserting all the information from one table to another."  Why does that constraint exist? Would other methods of backing up be acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to use so-called dynamic SQL, also known as "server side prepared statements" to do this. Ordinary SQL prohibits the use of variables for the names of tables or columns.

See here.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 1):

sounds like a bad idea but you could do it with `PREPARE statement FROM @sql` and `EXECUTE statement` like this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e83a/1/3)

sample table

```
CREATE table yourTable(id int auto_increment primary key,value varchar(50));
INSERT into yourtable(value) values ('test1'),('test2'),('test3'),('test4');
```

create a table with a time_stamp ending (in the example I am only recording down to the HOUR, you can add `_%i_%s` to the formatting if you want it down to the seconds.

```
SET @TimeStamp = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y_%m_%d_%H');

SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE table yourTable',@TimeStamp,'(id int auto_increment primary key,value varchar(50))');
PREPARE statement FROM @sql;
EXECUTE statement;

SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO yourTable',@TimeStamp,'(id,value) SELECT id,value FROM yourTable');
PREPARE statement FROM @sql;
EXECUTE statement;
```